# mail: How do I mark an email as unread?

Tags: email, mailx, maildir

I am using `mail` from GNU Mailutils to read the contents of a Maildir. For emails that have already been marked as read, is there a way to mark them as unread in `mail`?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this in mailutils, but it's easy in `mutt` (which I strongly recommend as a text-mode mail client).    Use `wn` to set the current message as New.   Or tag a whole bunch of messages (e.g. `T.<enter>` to tag all messages, or `Tfoo<enter>` to tag all messages matching "foo" or `T ~M 1-50` to tag msgs 1-50.  Read the docs - there are **lots** of tagging and searching options) and set them all as unread with `;wn`.  `;` applies the next command to all tagged messages, instead of the current message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

As of GNU Mailutils [version 3.14](https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=10094) (released on 2022-01-02), GNU Mailutils implements the "unread" command. An email can be marked as unread by pressing <kbd>U</kbd>.

---

Old answer:

This feature is not mentioned in POSIX `mailx`, and is not implemented by GNU Mailutils' `mailx`. S-nail and the BSDs' `mailx` support an `unread` command to mark emails as unread. However, BSD implementations of mailx do not support the Maildir format, so the solution is to use S-nail, which supports the Maildir format. Alternatively, one could move away from `mailx` and switch to using a simple email client such as Mutt.

Comment: Update: the "unread" command was added to GNU Mailutils on 2021-11-13 (commit [805a3f8](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/mailutils.git/commit/?id=805a3f8343f30a10056810f0fec4f0672dd3c297)). It will appear in the next release (the release right after version 3.13).